# Integrate urban airship using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, push-notification, urbanairship.com, integrate

I have an application want to integrate Urban Airship to push notification.
I dont use Android Studio, but I cant find any tutorial about integrate  Urban Airship with Eclipse.
Anyone can help me?
THank you.

Comment: Did you try Urban Airship's site: http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html

Comment: SDK have aar files. I dont know how to add them to my project in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Urban Airship dropped support for eclipse due to [ADT no longer being supported or developed by Google.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)

The last release that for eclipse style projects is 6.4.3. You can download the release from [bintray](https://bintray.com/urbanairship/android/urbanairship-sdk/6.4.3/view). Once downloaded you need to add the urbanairship-lib directory to your project along with the latest v4 support library and Google Play Services 8+.

Then add the following to your AndoridManifest.xml (replace ${applicationId} with your package name):

Permissions:

```
    <permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.UA_DATA" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.UA_DATA" />

    <!-- GCM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- ADM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
```

Components (add under the application tag):

```
<!-- ADM -->
<amazon:enable-feature
    android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging"
    android:required="false" />

<activity android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
<activity android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreActivity" />
<activity android:name="com.urbanairship.google.PlayServicesErrorActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />


<activity
    android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.LandingPageActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:theme="@style/LandingPageStyle">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.urbanairship.action.LANDING_PAGE_VIEW"
        android:resource="@layout/ua_activity_landing_page"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.urbanairship.push.iam.EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_SHOW"
        android:value="true" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.SHOW_LANDING_PAGE_INTENT_ACTION"/>

        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:scheme="message"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>

<service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService" android:label="Push Notification Service" />
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService" android:label="Event Service" />
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionService" />
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.richpush.RichPushUpdateService" />
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.location.LocationService" android:label="Segments Service" />

<service
    android:name="com.urbanairship.push.UAInstanceIDListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver"
          android:exported="false">

    <intent-filter android:priority="-999">
        <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.OPENED" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver
    android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GcmPushReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver
    android:name="com.urbanairship.push.AdmPushReceiver"
    android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<provider
    android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.urbanairship.provider"
    android:permission="${applicationId}.permission.UA_DATA"
    android:exported="true"
    android:multiprocess="true" />
```